# How to understand fomat printing in python with format printing?

Tags: python, printing, format

```
import math
print("%5.3f"%math.pi)
```

Answer is 3.142

1. How does %5. work?
2. when I use %.3f the output is 3.142 like %5.3f what's different at this point?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Comment: Reader's digest: http://pyformat.info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use %5.3f, it means that the decimal part is 3 digits long and the total size of the float is 5 characters.[Length (integer part + point + decimal part)=5]
Therefore, the output of %5.3f is not different from %.3f if, for example, you used %5.2f instead of %5.3f a space is created before the output so that the total number of characters is equal to 5.